# Passing Parameters to webservices

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, rest

Hi am developing a webservice whose end point 
the parameters being version(v1) and model(xyz)which would generate a uniqueid. Below is the response when i run this service.

```
   <ServiceResponse >
          <Uniqueid>3243jj3ni3533</Uniqueid>
           <Response>
```

My issue is I have to add another parameter to this service ie sitId. when I give the three parmeters ie version,xyz and sitid it should generate the uniqueid for me.
But I have a complication here, that is I have a customerID to which I have to link to the sitID and based on that If I give siteID as parameter,  uniqueid will be extracted.

Below is the controller.

```
      @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{version}/{model}/swid",   
      produces = { "application/xml",
        "application/json" })
      public final ModelAndView getUniqueId(@PathVariable final String version,
        @PathVariable final String model) {

      return getModelViewForSUniqueId(model);
       }
```

Please provide your suggestions as to how I can map the siteID and customerID to generate the UniqueID. Let me know if you need more details.
Thanks,

Comment: what is ur customerID? isnt it a parameter of the web service

Comment: nope it is not a parameter of the webservice. It is something I have in an xml file which is posted to get the response